# Memory Exception Occurred while fetching data from SQL for Bulk insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I just tried to bulk insert data which results to system.out.memory exception was thrown Even though the Ram as 260 GB and SQL Standard Edition 2017. Records was around 1 million , please give me any solution with my below code

```
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
            //  read the table structure from the database
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from xxxxx", constr);
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
            adapter.Fill(table);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(table.Rows.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(" Table End time..");
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("end----)";
            Console.WriteLine();
            SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(constr2);
            bulk.DestinationTableName = "xxxxxx";
            bulk.WriteToServer(table);
            Console.WriteLine()
```

Comment: The title says that a timeout occurred and the question says that memory was exhausted. Maybe you should edit your question so that it doesn't contradict itself.

Comment: So, when you did some proper testing and started of fetching a small number of records and gradually increased that number until it failed, what was the largest number of records you could successfully retrieve?

Comment: The best way is to do it all through the database with database links. If not, your option would be to do it in batch of say 100,000 records.

Comment: There's no need to buffer all the rows in client memory like you're doing.  Instead open a DataReader on the source query and pass that to SqlBulkCopy. SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DbDataReader) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserver?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlBulkCopy_WriteToServer_System_Data_Common_DbDataReader_.

Comment: The maximum rows I can fetch us around 585922 anything more than that results memory exception

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim ExcelConnection As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\your_path\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")

        ExcelConnection.Open()

        Dim expr As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
        Dim objCmdSelect As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(expr, ExcelConnection)
        Dim objDR As OleDbDataReader
        Dim SQLconn As New SqlConnection()
        Dim ConnString As String = "Data Source=DB_Name;Initial Catalog=Northwind.MDF;Trusted_Connection=True;"
        SQLconn.ConnectionString = ConnString
        SQLconn.Open()

        Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = New SqlBulkCopy(SQLconn)

            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "tblTest"

            Try
                objDR = objCmdSelect.ExecuteReader
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(objDR)
                ExcelConnection.Close()

                'objDR.Close()
                SQLconn.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Using

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Iam not using Excel here, I am just retrieving data from one database and inserting to another